Oracle Apex Add custom run button in Ig ROWS that will run a procedure
I have an Interactive Grid (Apex 22.1)
Select emp, bonus, dept from employees;
Now i need to add a button in the grid for each row.
The button would call a procedure that would eventually update the bonus of each employee by 5%.
So if i cluck on Update button for Employee John, for John it would update bonus to 5 % and so on.
How can this be achieved?
I have seen several solutions for adding buttons but going a step further and including the procedure is where i need help with...
I cannot share actual code so just tips/suggestions would also be very helpful.

Is the ig editable ?

No. It isn't .. IG should jut display and button should run

The biggest challenge is using the IG column values via the custom button. If on click of button even if i want to do an insert, i am not sure how to pull the IG valuesas it doesn't take column values with colon..

Does it have to be ig ? I have a couple of answers posted already about how to do this in ir

They want as IG but if IR works i can try convincing them.... :)

Here is an example on the EMP table. When a user clicks the button, the salary is updated by 1 through sql and the report refreshes.
create report

IG on EMP table, not editable
Add a column (using left click > Add Column) of type HTML Expression. Use the button builder to create the markup. For this example, I used the following markup: <button type="button" data-empno="&EMPNO!ATTR." class="increase-salary-Button t-Button t-Button--icon t-Button--warning t-Button--iconLeft"><span aria-hidden="true" class="t-Icon t-Icon--left fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></span>My Button</button>

Note that there are 2 additional attributes in the button tag:

the first one data-empno="&EMPNO!ATTR." adds an html data attribute that references the empno of the current row
the second one increase-salary-Button adds an additional class for the dynamic action click event to listen on.

create page item
Create a page item P132_EMPNO to hold the value of the empno when the button is clicked.
create dynamic action
Create DA with the following attributes:


Note the "Event Scope". This needs to be set to "dynamic" because you want the button to still work after the region refreshes. If it is set to "static" it will only work the first time.

Note the jQuery selector. This references the class on the button.

Create a DA action of type "Set Value" to set P132_EMPNO




Note the this.triggeringElement.dataset['empno'] to reference the data attribute
Create a DA action to execute the sql / pl/sql



Create a DA action to refresh the IG region.


A couple of notes:

For this button an HTML expression is used. A more modern approach is to use the cellTemplate property and define the button in the "Column Initialization JavaScript Function" of the column.
Instead of the "data-empno" approach, the apex actions framework can also be used. That would make it a bit more "apex native".


Amazing, this should definitely work!! Also if i wish to pull more values, ex: i want to do an insert in an audit table post procedure run using the same button. Do i need to initialize other columns also similar to EMPNO?

In this case EMPNO is primary key of that record so it'd be easier to get the other values from the table instead of from the UI. But if needed you could add more than one data attribute.

One last question, can we add server side condition to the dynamic column? Ex: something like only employees from Dept- Accounts should have this button? If its too much here i'll put up a new post..

Of course. In that case add the same condition to column AND dynamic action. It might be more appropriate to put an authorization scheme on it - that behaves like a server-side condition but is more relevant when a component needs to be rendered for a subset of users.
